# Ubuntu 16.04 server LAMP does not find php-into

Tags: server, 16.04

I am using *CakePHP 3.0* and it requires *PHP-INTL*. I have tried using
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl` but it can't find it.

Not sharp on other options. I need some help.

Comment: Attention Close voters. This one is really simple. See the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search with [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.0-intl) indicates that this is available for 16.04 by enabling the Universe repository (via Software and Updates) and issuing the following commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install php7.0-intl`

If you get a temporary failure resolving your selected mirror, you can wait and try again or Select a better mirror using the Software & Updates app by choosing Other from the Download From drop-down on the screen below.

[image: S&U]

Comment: I am getting Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com',

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: The result from 'sudo apt update' is:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I hit the stupid button...  The solution to this issue was the DNS entry when I configured the server and installed the code.  I had entered the DNS IP numbers and placed a ',' (comma) between the different IP's. This caused my configuration to not work at all.  Thanks for all who read this and I hope it helps someone else before they press the same button.